# failover-abort-no-good-slave error in Redis-Sentinel auto failover

Tags: redis, master-slave, redis-cluster, ubuntu-22.04, redis-sentinel

My redis sentinel is not working properly. As when my master (15...143) went down, one of the slaves elected as master but it is showing as failover-abort-no-good-slave error, why it is showing as Nogoodslave to promote from slaves to master. This results in selecting the old master (15...143) itself. Can anyone help?

---

+new-epoch 44
+try-failover master mymaster 15...143 6379
+vote-for-leader 466614318b614075783e046bafb66d9ae59adcde 44 <---------slave1 myid
9612c233dbbe3b43f919a98d563ce90154d7c503 voted for 466614318b614075783e046bafb66d9ae59adcde 44
+elected-leader master mymaster 15...143 6379
+failover-state-select-slave master mymaster 15...143 6379
-failover-abort-no-good-slave master mymaster 15...143 6379
Next failover delay: I will not start a failover before Thu Jan 25 12:48:50 2024

13.*.*.213:26379> SENTINEL get-master-addr-by-name mymaster

1. "15.*.*.143" <-----old master IP is showing
2. "6379"

---

Configuration details

=======================

---

redis1 15.*.*.143 8ce8bc1209aab6ba4b2e0479611b82e13ddead0e 172.*.*.106 < ----------------master
redis2 13.*.*.54  466614318b614075783e046bafb66d9ae59adcde 172.*.*.187 <-----------------slave1
redis3 13.*.*.213  9612c233dbbe3b43f919a98d563ce90154d7c503 172.*.*.118 <-----------------slave2

Sentinel configuration in master

===============================
bind 0.0.0.0
sentinel monitor mymaster 15.*.*.143 6379 2
sentinel down-after-milliseconds mymaster 5000
sentinel failover-timeout mymaster 60000
sentinel auth-pass mymaster masterpassword
protected-mode no

sentinel known-replica mymaster 13.*.*.213 6379
sentinel known-replica mymaster 13.*.*.54 6379
sentinel known-sentinel mymaster 172.*.*.118 26379 9612c233dbbe3b43f919a98d563ce90154d7c503
sentinel known-sentinel mymaster 172.*.*.187 26379 466614318b614075783e046bafb66d9ae59adcde

Sentinel configuration in slave1

================================

bind 0.0.0.0
sentinel monitor mymaster 15.*.*.143 6379 2
sentinel down-after-milliseconds mymaster 5000
sentinel failover-timeout mymaster 60000
sentinel auth-pass mymaster masterpassword
sentinel known-replica mymaster 13.*.*.213 6379
sentinel known-replica mymaster 13.*.*.54 6379
sentinel known-sentinel mymaster 172.*.*.118 26379 9612c233dbbe3b43f919a98d563ce90154d7c503
sentinel known-sentinel mymaster 172.*.*.106 26379 8ce8bc1209aab6ba4b2e0479611b82e13ddead0e

Sentinel configuration in slave2

================================
bind 0.0.0.0
sentinel monitor mymaster 15.*.*.143 6379 2
sentinel down-after-milliseconds mymaster 5000
sentinel failover-timeout mymaster 60000
sentinel auth-pass mymaster masterpassword

sentinel known-replica mymaster 13.*.*.213 6379
sentinel known-replica mymaster 13.*.*.54 6379
sentinel known-sentinel mymaster 172.*.*187 26379 466614318b614075783e046bafb66d9ae59adcde
sentinel known-sentinel mymaster 172.*.*.106 26379 8ce8bc1209aab6ba4b2e0479611b82e13ddead0e

---

Now i am getting the error like in between the slaves, one is voted as master but again when i am checking the get-mymaster command, it is show the old down master, not the new one.
and will show as nogoodslave as error

===================

In slave2 server

13.*.*.213:26379> SENTINEL get-master-addr-by-name mymaster

1. "15.*.*.143" <-----old master IP is showing
2. "6379"

In sentinal logs

+new-epoch 42
+vote-for-leader 466614318b614075783e046bafb66d9ae59adcde 42 <-------------slave1 myid
Next failover delay: I will not start a failover before Thu Jan 25 12:44:49 2024

--------------------------------------------------**
In slave1 server

redis-cli -h 13.*.*.54 -p 26379
13.*.*.54:26379> SENTINEL get-master-addr-by-name mymaster

1. "15.*.*.143" <------------------old master IP
2. "6379"

In sentinal logs

30299:X 25 Jan 2024 12:46:49.847 # +new-epoch 44
30299:X 25 Jan 2024 12:46:49.847 # +try-failover master mymaster 15.206.167.143 6379
30299:X 25 Jan 2024 12:46:49.851 # +vote-for-leader 466614318b614075783e046bafb66d9ae59adcde 44 <----------------------------slave1 myid
30299:X 25 Jan 2024 12:46:49.861 # 9612c233dbbe3b43f919a98d563ce90154d7c503 voted for 466614318b614075783e046bafb66d9ae59adcde 44
30299:X 25 Jan 2024 12:46:49.934 # +elected-leader master mymaster 15.206.167.143 6379
30299:X 25 Jan 2024 12:46:49.934 # +failover-state-select-slave master mymaster 15.206.167.143 6379
30299:X 25 Jan 2024 12:46:50.035 # -failover-abort-no-good-slave master mymaster 15.206.167.143 6379
30299:X 25 Jan 2024 12:46:50.106 # Next failover delay: I will not start a failover before Thu Jan 25 12:48:50 2024

===================

I need other slaves to get promoted as master when master is failed. Please help